# Gitlab ci/cd integration with Kubernetes on different project

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to deploy resources in Kubernetes cluster using gitlab ci/cd pipeline following https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/ci_cd_tunnel.html.
I am able successfully deploy the resources if both the agent configuration and the manifests are placed in same project.

```
kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME                           CLUSTER   AUTHINFO      NAMESPACE
 testgroup/agentk:myk8sagent   gitlab    agent:12755   
$ kubectl config use-context testgroup/agentk:myk8sagent
Switched to context "testgroup/agentk:myk8sagent".
$ kubectl get pods
No resources found in default namespace.
```

But when the manifests are in different project (but under the same group), it is not able to identify the context.

```
kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME   CLUSTER   AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE
$ kubectl config use-context testgroup/agentk:myk8sagent
error: no context exists with the name: "testgroup/agentk:myk8sagent"
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Also had such an issue, for now, it just doesn't work for different groups, only with in single group hierarchy. This is on v14.9.2

There is an issue opened: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/346636

As a workaround, we are using an agent per project group.

Comment: I am aware about the issue in different groups.. But I have projects under same group which are still not working.

Comment: You must have access configuration to make it work even with in the same group
cat .gitlab/agents/<agent-name>/config.yaml
ci_access:
  groups:
  - id: <group_name or path/to/group>

Comment: There is some limitation with comment formatting and editing, you can find config example here
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/ci_cd_workflow.html#authorize-the-agent-to-access-projects-in-your-groups